# allow for plural endings using regex with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This should be very simple for someone who knows regex. I don't need anything hardcore, just a simple altering of `.replace(/[e']?s$/, '');` below 
Someone else typed this code, it allows for plural endings on the ends of words in my specific situation, so if i typed "planet", it would also match "planets", and "planet's", but if I typed "hecktus", it wont match "hecktus", I think it's because the word ends with an "s", and that's throwing it off. Is there a better way to allow for plural endings for words, that would also allow the word "hecktus" to match "hecktus"?

```
$.trim(inputWords[i]).replace(/[e']?s$/, '');
```

Comment: Please tell us what the array `inputWords` contains

Comment: an array of words that will match words in a list. I need those words to allow for s, es, and 's endings, while not telling me the word "hecktus" doesn't match "hecktus" because it ends with an "s"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plurals in English are [a lot more complicated than that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural). Even not including irregulars, that code will not really catch a lot. You ran into one case where it fails, but there are going to be more. A single regular expression is not really something you can use to cover what you are thinking about (at least not from the looks of it). And if you are trying to detect if something is plural or singular, you are going have trouble.

Now, as for what to do with your input. I would recommend stemming things instead (unless you need to use the exact version given for some reason). A Google search prompted a [JavaScript Stemming library](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/js.txt) that is listed on the [Porter Stemming Algorithm page here](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/)

#### Update

Simple regex that will not match hecktus: `/([e']s|[^aiou]s)$/`

In english: Match an s if there is preceeded by an apostrophe, or e. Or match on an s that is proceeded by something other than a, i, o, or u.

Note that this will also grab the character before in the case of planets, so you can't just use it in a replace. You can instead do:

```
text.replace(/[e']s$/,'').replace(/([^aiou])s/, '$1');
```

Comment: I'm looking more for an altering of the `replace(/[e']?s$/, '');` that would allow the word 'hecktus' to match 'hecktus' without it saying there's no match. I just want to allow for 's, s, and es on the end of each word, without it telling me "hecktus" doesn't match "hecktus". I just need a better regex(i think i would call it regex?)

Comment: You are applying a stemming filter to only 1 side of your equality. This means you will get a lot of cases like this. The current regex, in plain english is this: "If there is an `s` at the end of the word, erase it. And if there is either an apostrophe or an `e` before that, replace that as well." I'll update with a "solution" to this specific word, but you will find situations in which it does not work.

Comment: awesome thank you. I don't need it perfect, it's meant for small things and the words are simple enough to where I shouldn't have any problems, because I choose the words that can be matched.